# Is a 'scheduled' send feature an improvement on the user experience (for the recipient) for Gmail?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, email, trust

I know that in business or enterprise software, a scheduled send feature is vital for planning and co-ordination of activities that have defined window of time for its implementation or execution.

However, in what would probably be a largely personal userbase, Gmail's roll-out of the [Schedule send](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9214606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) seems to be a useful feature at first glance, given that it provides the same level of flexibility and control over when emails go out.

On the other hand, from the perspective of the receiver, the inability to distinguish between a scheduled email versus one that is sent normally after it has been composed would seem to erode some of the trust and credibility that we associate with emails that are of a personal nature (that we don't normally expect or associate with emails of a commercial nature).

I am wondering if this feature takes into consideration of what the recipient might feel since they cannot know if an email is scheduled or not and may assume this to be the case when it might not be. Is this something that has been researched or considered from the recipient's point of view?

Comment: Why do you think this will bring trust and credibility issues ?

Comment: Using various tools you can already schedule sending emails from any email address (MailChimp, campaign monitor, etc). So this issue would already exist without the new Gmail feature you are mentioning. How is this different?